# Is it possible to create a sticky vertical column using Bootstrap without having to specify position?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the effect of a sticky column to the right of the text, just like in [Bootstrap web page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Here's my code:

```
             <nav class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"  data-spy="affix"  data-offset-top="205">
                <div class="panel panel-default" >
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h1>Table des matières</h1></div>
                    <section class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                        Nullam luctus nisi est, id blandit nunc tristique vel! 
                    </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

(There is another bar on the left which takes up the 8 previous columns)

This sort of works: the sidebar appears in the right place when the page loads, and when I scroll up it stays stuck to the top, **but** it also jumps across to the left and sits on top of the left-most column, acquiring a width which doesn't seem to have much to do with anything (5 columns and a bit wide).

Looking at the documentation it seems that I have to configure the .affix class myself in the CSS so that it stays in the right place (which seems a bit strange, I just want it to stay in the column it comes from!). But what values should I use? I have tried putting this in my CSS:

```
.affix {
top: 20px;
left: 62%;
width: 25%;
}
```

and it just about works (the left positioning and the width is just slightly off), but of course it doesn't work properly when I look at it in a different width browser window. Does this mean that I have to put all the appropriate media-queries? Or could I use a bit of calculation on the basis of column widths etc? I have some very basic SASS knowledge - would this perhaps be a way forward, to calculate these widths by compiling bootstrap in SASS?

Also, if anyone has an idea about how to reveal what chapter you're on in the sidebar (exactly like on the Bootstrap page) then that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add `right: 0;` to your affix property in CSS to keep it pinned right. I went ahead and created a CodePen of a working model so you can check it out below.

For the design changes to the links based on position you need to add the scrollspy class to your `ul` parent and then style the `a` links accordingly.

Note the added classes to the `div` and `ul` containing the `li` nav elements.

For responsive design you will need to also set the appropriate col widths for xs, sm, and md.

[Bootstrap Affix Right-Side](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/xEGgOE)

Comment: I think maybe this only works with a fluid container. My container is fixed and adding `right:0;` causes the block to jump across to the right hand side of the page (I presume, to the right of the body). I've tried playing with different settings for `position` on the parent elements, but to no avail. Of course I may also be missing something when transposing your solution to my own code.

Comment: `"I'm trying to get the effect of a sticky column to the right of the text"` 
I thought to the right was what you are wanting? Have you used developer tools in your browser to inspect the page?

Comment: @MartinK

Also note that your container should NOT be `position: fixed` to start. You should set it to `position: relative`, relative really means "relative to it's own normal positioning allowing you to adjust via `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties. Bootstrap then will allow you to scroll to your set `data-offset-top="60"`, then `affix-top` is replaced by `affix` which has a `position: fixed`.